# JQuery Ajax Call for multiple text inputs

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a wider form in my HTML, but within it are fields for name and address. These fields are within a div of their own. I want when any of these fields are changed to post an ajax request using jQuery so I can update the session and retain them without having to submit the whole form. Once the data is posted I can handle that, but I'm struggling to get the data to post when I change the data in the fields.

I'm trying to use jQuery and PHP.

The part of the form is as below:

```
<div id="del_add">
<h4>Delivery Address</h4>
<label>Name:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
<label>Address:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="add1" /><br />
<input type="text" name="add2" /><br />
<input type="text" name="add3" /><br />
<input type="text" name="add4" /><br />
<input type="text" name="add5" />
</div>
```

I'm getting myself thoroughly confused with this, so I hope someone can help me...

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you struggling with? What have you done so far?

Comment: If I understand, you want to submit each individual field via `ajax` when it is changed. What's the logic behind that?

Comment: Are the text inputs dynamically created or is this a static page? Have you already written a routine to save the data to the server? If so, what is it called? Why aren't you using any `id` on your elements?

Comment: @MMM I'm struggling to capture the data and send it. I have tried many things such as: 
` $('#del_add').change(function () {
  $.post( '/test.php', $('#del_add').serialize() );
  alert("Changed");
 });`

Comment: @DevlshOne - the inputs are static. The routine hasn't been written yet, if I can get the data posted then I can deal with it. No reason for not using ids on the elements, I thought it might be cleaner to combine all within one div that already exists anyway. I'm new to this, so if I'm doing it wrong I'd appreciate any help

Comment: @Softstag So, you want to submit just the `del_add` div of this form? How do you plan to trigger that? Will it have it's own unique button? Just an FYI, this http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ plugin makes form-handling very, very simple.

Comment: @DevlshOne - Yes this is the only data that needs submitting. Was planning on sending the data as the form changed, so when the value of one of the fields is changed post the data. Will take a look at the plugin - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the rough solution based upon what you've given.

```
$('#del_add').on('change',':text',function(e) {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.get('data.processing.php',{posted:data});
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This got me on the right track. Here is what I ended up with that worked for me:
`    $('#del_add').on('change',':text',function(e) {
    $.post('data.processing.php',$(this).serialize());
    });`

Comment: Yep! I usually assign a variable before `post`ing so I can send it to the console if I need to verify it's contents.